# Allow multiple subdomain in laravel without making subdomain as route variable?

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, laravel-5, laravel-routing

My subdomains are

```
domain1 = dev1.myapp.com,
domain2 = dev2.myapp.com,
domain3 = dev3.myapp.com
...
```

Using below code causing problem with first parameter in laravel controller,

```
> Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function() {
> Route::get('/get_data/{id?}', 'DataController@getData');
> })
```

I am getting subdomain value(`dev1`,`dev2`,`dev3`) instead of `$id value` in controller in `getData` method.

How to update my code to allow all subdomain, without making subdomain as first parameter in each method of controller.

Please share your idea.

Comment: Make sure you've bind `{account}` with your model.

Comment: @RifkiAriaGumelar : You mean in controller's method `getData` ?

Comment: I don't need `$account` anywhere so should I need to include in all the sub route ?

Comment: Let's make it more clear, do you want to get your subdomains based on user id something like `1.myapp.com`?

Comment: @RifkiAriaGumelar, It will be like `dev1.myapp.com/get_data/1` or  `dev2.myapp.com/get_data/1`

Comment: I need to use subdomain, but I do not need to use `account` value as a route variable as first parameter in laravel controller.

Comment: please help me to understand that its possible or not ?

Comment: You can define your routes as a separate variable function and pass it to each sub domain groups

Comment: Can you provide an example of this ?

Answer (score 10):

Since you don't want to use `{account}` variable on your controller methods, you can define your routes in a variable and pass it to each your subdomain group, here is the example:

```
$subdomainRoutes = function () {
    Route::get('get_data/{id?}', function ($id) {
        //
    });
};

Route::group(['domain' => 'dev1.myapp.com'], $subdomainRoutes);
Route::group(['domain' => 'dev2.myapp.com'], $subdomainRoutes);
Route::group(['domain' => 'dev3.myapp.com'], $subdomainRoutes);
```

**EDIT**

If your sub domains are dynamic then you can use a `middleware`, create a middleware something like:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SubDomainAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $server = explode('.', $request->server('HTTP_HOST'));
        $subdomain = $server[0];

        // check if sub domain exists, replace with your own conditional check
        if (! Account::where('slug', $subdomain)->first()) {
            return abort(404); // or redirect to your homepage route.
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register your `middleware` in `Kernel.php`

```
'subdomain' => \App\Http\Middleware\SubDomainAccess::class,
```

Then use it on your `routes.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'subdomain'],  function () {
    Route::get('/get_data/{id?}', 'DataController@getData');
});
```

Comment: `dev1`, `dev2` & `dev3` all are dynamic and there would be many more accounts like this.