# Redirect dynamically created subdomains to main page in Laravel 5.3

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-5.3, wildcard-subdomain

I am working on multi-tenant approach. I created a new tenant with all its information in database including its sub-domain. My approach is separate database and separate sub-domains for each customer. So, I am creating a sub-domain on button click and saving it in database. Now, I am lost on my way how to redirect that sub-domain to main page. I just need to redirect it to main page nothing else, I will work on separate db connection later. I also created the wildcard subdomain entry from cpanel. I am working on wildcard domains for the first time and also I am on my way of learning laravel.

Here is my code:

routes/web.php

```
 Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.example.com/tracker'), function()
 {
      Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

 });
```

HomeController.php

```
 <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class HomeController extends Controller
  {

   public function index()
   {
        return view('welcome');
   }
 }
```

I know there are lot of things missing that's why its not working but I tried many solutions I found on google and stackoverflow but still I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me how to overcome this issue. Also, please if anyone have good tutorial on this topic, please share that with me.

Thank you

Comment: anybody there? please help. I really need its solution. Thank you. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using this solution on stackoverflow.

[Allow multiple subdomain in laravel without making subdomain as route variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359981/allow-multiple-subdomain-in-laravel-without-making-subdomain-as-route-variable)

It worked like a charm. Hope it helps someone.

Thank you.