# Laravel - Route admin user to subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, routes, admin

I am building a website with **Laravel** where a user can be assigned as an admin. The admins should only navigate through the dashboard which will be under a subdomain **admin.domain.com** and the other users can only navigate through the main domain **domain.com**.

My question is how can i restrict the admin to view the section where normal users can and vice versa. I want admins to navigate only through all subdomain routes only (for example **admin.domain.com/statistics**) and not **domain.com/categories**. These are my routes for the admin and public part.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.domain.com'], function () {
    /* Admin routes */
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'domain.com'], function () {
    /* Public routes */
}
```

I want when i login as an admin to be automatically redirected to the subdomain and if i type a public route i want to be redirected back to the root admin route.

One of the solutions i was thinking was to wrap the admin and public routes with a middleware that will redirect the user depending on its type whether its admin or normal user but im not sure if this is a proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: Google is your best friend. Look what a simple search can get you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359981/allow-multiple-subdomain-in-laravel-without-making-subdomain-as-route-variable You can expand on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could Use 2 Middlewares

1- redirect non-admins to public area will be placed in the first group

2- redirect admins to admins subdomain will be placed in the second group

Comment: Thanks ... seems like a legit solution... Will try that